# Condition about functional equation has a solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, functional-equations

**Problem :**

Let $P(x, y)$ be a polynomial respect to $x, y$.

Find a condition about $P$ where functional equation of $f$

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+P(x,y)$$

has a solution. (Where $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.)

---

This problem came from some functional equation problems below :

**P1 :**

Find a differentiable $f$ which satisfies
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+2xy$$

**S1 :**

Set $x=y=0$ then we get $f(0)=0$.

From definition of derivative,

$$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{f(y)+2xy}{y} = 2x+f'(0)$$

This implies $$f(x)=x^2 + cx$$

for some constant $c$.

Plugging this to original functional equation,

$$\text{LHS} = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + cx + cy$$
$$\text{RHS} = x^2 + y^2 + cx + cy + 2xy$$

which are same, so we find a solution of original functional equation.

---

**P2 :**

Find a differentiable $f$ which satisfies
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+3x^2y$$

**S2 :**

Similar way, $f(0)=0$ and from definition of derivative,

$$f'(x)=f'(0)+3x^2$$

which implies $$f(x)=x^3 + cx$$

for some constant c. However If we plug this to original functional equation

$$\text{LHS} = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3 + cx + cy$$
$$\text{RHS} = x^3 + 3x^2y + y^3 +cx + cy$$

which are **not** same.

---

So, I want to know a condition of $P(x, y)$ which makes a functional equation of $f$ (which likes below form) has a solution :

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+P(x,y)$$

Where $f$ is a differentiable function.

I find that WLOG $P(0, 0) = 0$

Because, if $P(0, 0) = a \neq 0$, add $a$ both side then we can write as

$$(f(x+y)+a) = (f(x)+a) + (f(y)+a) + Q(x, y)$$

Where $Q(x, y)$ is a polynomial respect to $x, y$ which satisfies $Q(0, 0) = 0$.

Substitution $g(x) = f(x)+a$ changes this equation to :

$$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)+Q(x, y)$$

So I can assume that WLOG $P(0,0)=0$.

---

**Added**

Conjecture :

$P(x,y)$ must be constant or middle term(Cross -terms) of binomial expansion, i.e.

$$ (x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + \mathbf{2xy}$$
or
$$(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + \mathbf{3x^2y + 3xy^2}$$

I don't have a proof but I made some try and common thing of $P(x,y)$ is this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, another condition is that you need $P(x,y) = P(y,x)$, due to the symmetry in the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the terms $f(x+y)$ and $f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: It seems that since $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x) + P(x, y)}{y}$ must exist for all  $x$, the $f(x)$ must be equal to $-P(x, 0)$, that is being itself a polynomial. Obvously, for any polynomial $f$ there is a satisfactory $P$.

Comment: @user58697 There exists $f'(x)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(y)+P(x,y)}{y}=f'(0)+P_y(x,0)$, see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4770435/71850) for the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete description of the required polynomials $P(x,y)$ is provided by the following simple theorem.

**Theorem.** Let $P(x, y)\in \mathbb R[x,y]$ be a polynomial and $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function  such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+P(x,y)$ for each $x,y\in\mathbb R$. Then $f$ is a polynomial.

*Proof*. For each $x,y\in \mathbb R$, $y\ne 0$ we have $\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\frac{f(y)+P(x,y)}{y}$.
Since there exists $f'(x)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}$, we have that $f(0)+P(x,0)=0$ and $f'(x)=f'(0)+P_y(x,0)$.
Since the latter expression is a polynomial with respect to $x$, so are $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$. $\square$

Comment: In fact, I think $f$ is still a polynomial  if you only assume that it is continuous.

Comment: Yes, $P$ will be polynomial. But this is not enough to guarantee the functional equation of $f$ has a solution. As you can see (in my context), if $P = 2xy$, the functional equation has a solution. But if $P = 3x^2y$, it doesn't.

Comment: @bFur4list The functional equation has a solution iff there exists a polynomial $f\in \mathbb R[x]$ such that $P(x,y)=f(x+y)-f(x)+f(y)$ for each $x,y$ in $\mathbb R$. That is, the set of $P(x,y)$ such that the functional equation has a solution is a linear space over $\mathbb R$ with the basis $\{(x+y)^n-x^n-y^n:n\in\{0,2,3,4,\dots\}\}$.

Comment: I have a conjecture which is exactly same with your attempt. Can you add details about your attempt?

Comment: @bFur4list What details do you need? The claim about $P(x,y)$ from my last comment follows from Theorem so straightforwardly that I even did not formulate it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can use L'Hôpital's rule to solve for $f(x).$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x+y)&=&f(x)+f(y)+P(x,y)\\
f(0)&=&-P(0,0)\\
f'(x)&=&\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}y\\
&=&\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(y)+P(x,y)}{y}\\
f'(x)&=&f'(0)+P_y(x,0)\\
f(x)&=&\int_0^xP_y(t,0)dt+f'(0)x-P(0,0)
\end{eqnarray}
Substituting this into the functional equation, we get that $P(x,y)$ must satisfy
\begin{eqnarray}
P(x,y)-P(0,0)&=&\int_0^{x+y}P_y(t,0)dt-\int_0^xP_y(t,0)dt-\int_0^yP_y(t,0)dt\\
\left.P(x,t)\right|_0^y&=&\int_x^{x+y}P_y(t,0)dt-\int_0^yP_y(t,0)dt\\
\int_0^yP_y(x,t)dt&=&\int_0^y\left(P_y(t+x,0)-P_y(t,0)\right)dt\\
\int_0^y(\left.P_y(s,t)\right|_0^x+P_y(0,t))dt&=&\int_0^y\left.P_y(s,0)\right|_t^{t+x}dt\\
\int_0^y\int_0^xP_{xy}(s,t)dsdt+P(0,0)&=&\int_0^y\int_0^xP_{xy}(s+t,0)dsdt\\
P(0,0)&=&\int_0^y\int_0^x(P_{xy}(s+t,0)-P_{xy}(s,t))dsdt\\
&=&\int_0^y\int_0^x\left.-P_{xy}(s+t-r,r)\right|_0^tdsdt\\
&=&\int_0^y\int_0^x\int_0^t(P_x-P_y)_{xy}(s+t-r,r)drdsdt
\end{eqnarray}
For example, $P(x,y)=2xy$ is a solution.
$$0=\int_0^y\int_0^x\int_0^t0drdsdt$$
But $P(x,y)=3x^2y$ isn't.
$$0\ne3xy^2=\int_0^y\int_0^x\int_0^t6drdsdt$$

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. I have a conjecture now : $P(x,y)$ must be middle term of binomial expansion (ex : $(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + \mathbf{3x^2y + 3xy^2}$). I will append this soon, can you verify this?